# MSSQL 30-60-90-120 day query grouping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am a bit rusty with MSSQL but I am trying to write a query that shows Inventory Movements in periods of 30 days.

In Short, I have the below queries that I run a few times with different datediff paramaters

```
SELECT * FROM InvMovements
Where EntryDate between DATEADD(day,datediff(DAY,0,GETDATE()) -30,0)
and
DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()) - 0)
Order by EntryDate DESC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM InvMovements
Where EntryDate between DATEADD(day,datediff(DAY,0,GETDATE()) - 60,0)
and
DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()) -31,0)
Order by EntryDate DESC
```

What I would like to get to, even if its using SSRS is it all grouped by the individual queries, so result set is under its grouping
30 60  90

Not sure if this is possible in a normal query or if i need to utilise SSRS and column individual queries.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please provide an example e.g. as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: SELECT * FROM InvMovements
Where EntryDate between DATEADD(day,datediff(DAY,0,GETDATE()) - 30,0)
and
DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
Order by EntryDate DESC

SELECT * FROM InvMovements
Where EntryDate between DATEADD(day,datediff(DAY,0,GETDATE()) - 60,0)
and
DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()) -31 ,0)
Order by EntryDate DESC

InvMovements table will have a StockCode, Price and Date

Perfect Result would be

0-30    31-60    61-90
StockCode, Price, Date StockCode, Price, Date StockCode, Price, Date
StockCode, Price, Date StockCode, Price, Date StockCode, Price, Date

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick code sample as divided by 30.41666666666667 as there it is 365 days  divided by 12 month
TimeCreated = TIMEstamP

the group by will be 1 to 12 each one is 30 days

also on MSSQL when you Cast as int it takes only the interger it does not round it up not sure about MYSQL  you can test it by select cast(0.99 as int) you should receive 0

```
 /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

SELECT sum(isnull(Quantity,1)) as QTY,cast(DATEDIFF(day,TimeCreated,getdate())/30.41666666666667 as int) Which30Days
  FROM [estimatelinedetail] left join  [estimate] on estimate.TxnID=estimatelinedetail.IDKEY

  where ItemRef_ListID ='800022B3-1567464337' and TimeCreated>= GETDATE()-365
  group by cast(DATEDIFF(day,TimeCreated,getdate())/30.41666666666667 as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the **DATEDIFF** between the **EntryDate** and today, divide it by **30** and **INTERGER**ize it for the groups. Then **add 1** so the 0 - 29 days = 1 and **multiply by 30** to get the day group.

```
SELECT * , 
(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, EntryDate, GETDATE()) / 30 as INTEGER) + 1) * 30 AS PERIOD 
FROM InvMovements
Order by EntryDate DESC
```

Not sure what syntax is different for MySQL though. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  declare @CurrentDate datetime = convert(date,GETDATE())
   ;with M(i,o) as (
        select * from (
        values (0,30),(31,60),(61,90),(91,120)) R(i,o)
    )
    select
    Period = convert(nvarchar,m.i)+'-'+convert(nvarchar,m.o),
     *
    FROM InvMovements
    Where EntryDate between DATEADD(day,-m.o,@CurrentDate)
                        and DATEADD(day,-m.i,@CurrentDate)+0.99995
    Order by EntryDate DESC
```